# Real semisimple Lie group with infinitely many connected components?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is it possible for a real semisimple Lie group to have infinitely many connected components? If so, what is an example?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by semisimple? (For a popular definition, the condition depends only on the Lie algebra, so the number of connected components is entirely immaterial)

Comment: Yes I was thinking of a semisimple Lie group as that which has a semisimple Lie algebra. Are there other frequently used definitions?

Comment: You might have meant a Lie group whose category of finite-dimensional representations is semisimple. This rules out many possible values of $\pi_0$. Anyway, presumably Mariano asked precisely because that definition places no constraints on the connected components whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,
$$\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{Z}.$$
(Or any real semisimple group times a countably infinite discrete group.) The point is that
$$\mathrm{Lie}(G\times H)=\mathrm{Lie}(G)\times\mathrm{Lie}(H)$$
and $\mathrm{Lie}(H)=\{0\}$ for a discrete group $H$.

Comment: Are there real semisimple Lie groups with infinitely many components that are not of the form $G\times H$ where $H$ is discrete infinite? (I'm trying to understand to what extent one can just think about semisimple groups that are almost-connected.)

Comment: I would love to have an example too.