# Does a linear semisimple Lie group have only finitely many connected components?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a semisimple real Lie group that is *linear*, i.e. admits a closed embedding $G \hookrightarrow \text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Does $G$ have only finitely many connected components?

If $G$ is  real algebraic, then this is known to be true. On the other hand, if we drop the linearity condition, then $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}) \times \mathbb{Z}$ is a counterexample.

Related to this questions is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175501/real-semisimple-lie-group-with-infinitely-many-connected-components) and the comments there.

Comment: Can you not build a counter example like $SL(2, \mathbb{R}) \times SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ which sits in $GL(4, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: You have to spell out what definition of semisimplicity you are using. It is common to include connectedness (or finite number of components) in the definition. Also, $SL(2,R)\times Z$ is a linear group!

Answer (score 1):

This is false, just like the other question, because $\mathbb Z$ is a linear Lie group. It embeds in $\operatorname{GL}_1(\mathbb R)$ by $n \mapsto 2^n$.

Comment: Isn't a semisimple group not abelian by definition?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, because a semisimple Lie group is often connected by definition, and then $G$ is not abelian because $\mathfrak g$ is not abelian. No under the definition of the OP, which I think is: "$G$ is semisimple iff its connected component is semisimple".

Comment: You have to spell out what definition of semisimplicity you are using. It is common to include connectedness (or finite number of components) in the definition.